# Any security vulnerabilities with this JSON response?

Tags: json, security, networking

I had to update a form on a certain webpage to change something i wanted.
I failed to do so, but instead of sending a simple text reply saying 'This cannot work' for example, they sent a whole JSON response on the display.
I'm just curious, does this response pose any security vulnerabilities for either me or the server i contacted to process my request?

P.S. The '***'s in the response are so because I'm not sure if providing that info is the right thing to do.
However, even without it, the response is fairly intuitive.

This is the response:

**{"name":"StatusCodeError","statusCode":409,"message":"409 - [object Object]","error":{"status":"failure","message":"Email already taken.","code":91,"data":null,"error":{"message":"None"}},"options":{"uri":"*********","method":"POST","headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer *********=","Cookie":"*********=;cm_sub=denied","User-Agent":"********","Accept-Language":"en-US","Original-Accept-Language":"********","X-********-InstallId":"*****","X-*****-AppState":"active","X-*****-Parent-Rid":"********","X-*****-Root-Rid":"********","X-*****-Rid":"*****","X-Pixel-Ratio":1,"X-*****-App-Type":5,"X-Prefer-User-Locale":"1","X-Real-Ip":"********","X-*****-Real-Ip":"*****","X-*****-Csrf":"********","X-*****-Browser-Extension-Installed":"false","X-********-Referrer":"********","X-Bot":"false","X-Referrer":"********","X-Url":"********"},"form":{"base_scheme":"https","client_id":1431601,"timestamp":*****,"country":"US","email":"*****","oauth_signature":"********"},"traceId":false,"parseJson":true,"resolveWithFullResponse":true,"json":true,"simple":true},"response":{"statusCode":409,"body":{"status":"failure","message":"********","code"********,"data":null,"error":{"message":"None"}},"headers":{"server":"nginx","date":"Sun, 10 Mar 2019 16:08:31 GMT","content-type":"application/json","content-length":"112","connection":"close","*****-version":"*****","x-content-type-options":"*****","x-frame-options":"DENY","*****-generated-by":"********"},"request":{"uri":{"protocol":"http:","slashes":true,"auth":null,"host":"*****","port":"*****","hostname":"localhost","hash":null,"search":null,"query":null,"pathname********","path":"/v3/users/settings/","href":"********"},"method":"POST","headers":{"Authorization":"********","Cookie*********","User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/******** Safari/537.36","Accept-Language":"en-US","Original-Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.9","X-*****-InstallId":"********","X-*****-AppState":"active","X-*****-Parent-Rid":"********","X-*****-Root-Rid":"*************","X-*****-Rid":"*****","X-Pixel-Ratio":1,"X-*****-App-Type":5,"X-Prefer-User-Locale":"1","X-Real-Ip":"*****","X-*****-Real-Ip":"********","X-********-Csrf":"********","X-*****-Browser-Extension-Installed":"false","X-********-Referrer":"*************","X-Bot":"false","X-Referrer":"********","X-Url":"********","content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","accept":"application/json","content-length":179}}}}**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I learned from this server response. The first thing I noticed is your protocol is using http.

> "protocol":"http:"

HTTP is a plaintext and unencrypted form of communication. This is important to note because if someone is sniffing your traffic, they will be able to read the transmission as you have posted it here (without the *****'s blocking sensitive data).

The next thing I noticed is your authorization token.

> "Authorization":"Bearer *********="

Given that the message is in plaintext, an attacker will be able to steal your token. Using this token an attacker can communicate with the server as an authorized user, gaining access to (and possibly the ability to modify) private information.

On the flip side, since we assume the attacker has sniffed your unencrypted traffic. They can also make note of your client's computer/ browser information:

> "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/******** Safari/537.36"

From this info, the attacker can gather that the client is using windows 8.1 and what browsers/versions are installed on the client's computer. With these system specs, the attacker can launch a targeted attack on the client's computer (especially if you have an outdated/ insecure OS or browser version).

So to answer your question, yes **there are security vulnerabilities for both the client and server**.

However, simply switching from HTTP to HTTPS would make a big difference in limiting your exposure.

Comment: Splendid, but what from these pose threats to the server?
Sorry I'm still new to this.

I see the ways my identity can be changed and all, but there's nothing to say about the svr.

Comment: @kushshah If the attacker gets your token, they will be able to impersonate the client. This means the attacker can make the same server calls as the client; these calls may by malicious or seeking sensitive data. Thus, the server is compromised.